# A full crawl cannot start until the current

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to activate PDF search in SPF 2010. I have followed the KB and done the following:

-Installed the Ifilter 64bit.

-Then added the pdf image and xml entries on 14 Hive.

-After that  I have added added regedit entries and have run the vbs script.

-Now when I am trying to run the full crawl stsadm command it is showing error that 
"it cannot start until the current incremental crawl completes or stopped"

Let me know 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to do the following:

> Disable loopbackcheck and try again:   Click Start, click Run, type
>   regedit, and then click OK
>
> In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
>
> Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value. (In Win
>   2008, its DWORD 32bit)
>
> Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
>
> Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
>
> In the Value data box, type 1 and then click OK.
>
> Quit Registry Editor.
>
> You may need to restart your server.

this was taken from here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/bg-BG/sharepoint2010setup/thread/ee30d4e2-3509-4080-b1e1-a0f600e5cc68

**EDIT**

once you have done the above you need to carry on with the KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2518465

then do the full crawl:

```
stsadm –o spsearch –action fullcrawlstart
```

To make sure its working and has crawled you need to performe a search for a pdf document. You should see any new pdf's in the search list!

Hope it helps :)

Comment: But I cannot restart the server because its a LIVE one

Comment: I ran it it went successful. But how would I know that now the pdf search is activated

Comment: How to verify??

Comment: have you run the full crawl again? and has it gone sucessfull?

Comment: iv ammended my answer ;)